# PayPal ExpressCheckoutForDigital goods api submitting two payment transactions

Tags: asp.net, paypal

We have been using Express Checkout for Digital Goods on our website for 5 years. Recently customers have been having issues purchasing our software. Some get hangs on the PayPal page and are not returned to our site. In cheking our logs I see that most transactions are submitting payments twice using the original token which causes an error message in the acknowledgement. Any thoughts on what might be happening? As I said, the site and pages have been working for several years. This seems to be a recent change somewhere.

Comment: I think this needs a bit more info. When you say 'some get hangs on the paypal page', do you mean that the transaction stops when they go to paypal? It so, this is a paypal issue. My other question is do you have a unique identity for each paypal transaction to prevent duplicates in your code?

Comment: What I mean by hangs is that the PayPal lightbox does not close, I little process rotor indicating "Loading": just spins. There is some javascript that I got from PayPal to close the Lightbox PayPal window and I am wondering if this isn't working. Possibly the browsers to process it the way it was written in 2012.